# Json.NET Windows Store App certification crash

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, json.net

This might not be related 100% to Json.NET but since it's the component that crashes...

The serialization works just fine until the second test of the Windows App Cert Kit. Starting with this app launch it throws the following exception:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException Entry point was not found.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetFieldsAndProperties(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\ReflectionUtils.cs:line 661
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 267
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 845
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 349
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 734
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 232
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe(Object value) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 77
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value) in \Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 58
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value) in \Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 608
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in \Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 749
```

The code looks like this...

```
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = "a", test = "test" });
```

After running WACK on the app I have to reinstall it to make it work again.

Does anyone know how WACK runs the app? I suppose it somehow simultates various environments at each launch but I can't find out how it messes my app.

Comment: I have the same issue and I discovered that this happens because WACK compiles Json.NET in native code and this leads to this strange issue. If you go to the package folder and delete Json.NET from AC\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0_32 it will start to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by Json.NET using an anonymous type in GetFieldsAndProperties. WinRT must have a bug with them when used in a third party dll.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. I confirm it's fixed in the Release 7

I opened a bug on Connect, because this is a blocking issue for using the grate JSNO.Net on Windows 8 Metro.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749011/ngen-failing-with-json-net-metro

Comment: It's fixed in current release, Json.NET 4.5 Release 7

Comment: I tried but problem is still present in Release 7. certification passes but EntryPointNotFoundException is still present at runtime after ngen compiled assembly

Comment: Could you provide the complete stack trace. I need to know where the exception is being generated from to fix it.